# $\sin2 \theta$ + $\cos2 \theta$ = $\sin \theta$ + $\cos \theta$ proof

Tags: trigonometry

how to proof that the following one is true

$\sin2 \theta + \cos2 \theta = \sin \theta + \cos \theta$

I tried to do like this

L.H.S.

$= 2\sin\theta\cos\theta + \cos^2 \theta - \sin^2 \theta $

$= \sin\theta\cos\theta + \cos^2 \theta + \sin\theta\cos\theta - \sin^2 \theta$

$= \cos \theta(\sin\theta + \cos \theta) + \sin \theta(\cos\theta - \sin \theta)$

Then what should I do ?

Am I on the right way ?

Comment: The statement is false,take $\theta =\frac { \pi  }{ 4 } $,$$\\ \sin { \left( 2\cdot \frac { \pi  }{ 4 }  \right)  } +\cos { \left( 2\cdot \frac { \pi  }{ 4 }  \right)  } =\sin { \left( \frac { \pi  }{ 4 }  \right)  } +\cos { \left( \frac { \pi  }{ 4 }  \right)  } \\ 1\neq \sqrt { 2 } $$

Comment: I think this is not generally true .

Comment: This can not hold for all $\theta$ ! Take for example $\theta=\tfrac{\pi}{2}$. In fact you are asked to solve an equation : for which values of $\theta$ does the equality is valid...

Comment: oh really ? Thanks . I think in a wrong way

Comment: Shouldn't the question be 'for which $\theta$ ...

Comment: I have undone your last change to the question's title, as the question has been _answered_, but actually not _closed_.

Comment: If this was true, it would be a very interesting trigonometric relation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $\theta=\pi$ you have

LHS: $\sin(2\pi) + \cos(2\pi) = 0 + 1 = 1$
RHS: $\sin\pi + \cos\pi = 0 + (-1) = -1$

hence the equality does not hold and can't be proven.

Answer (score 3):

Let $(*)$ be the equation to solve.

$$ (*) \Leftrightarrow \sqrt2 \cos(2\theta-\frac{\pi}{4}) = \sqrt2 \cos(\theta-\frac{\pi}{4})$$

$$\Leftrightarrow 2\theta-\frac{\pi}{4} \equiv \theta-\frac{\pi}{4} \pmod{2\pi}  \text{ or } 2\theta-\frac{\pi}{4} \equiv -\theta+\frac{\pi}{4} \pmod{2\pi}$$

$$ \Leftrightarrow \theta \equiv 0 \pmod{2\pi} \text{ or } \theta \equiv \frac{\pi}{6} \pmod{\frac{2\pi}{3}}$$

Comment: I think this was the intention.

Answer (score 2):

Use Simpson formula instead:
$$
\sin(2x) + \cos(2x) = \sin(x) + \cos(x)\implies 
\sin(2x) - \sin(x) = \cos(x) - \cos(2x)\implies \\
\sin(x/2)( \cos(3x/2) - \sin(3x/2)) =0.
$$

Then solve these two equations:
$$
\sin(x/2) = 0 \\
\cos(3x/2) = \sin(3x/2).
$$

Comment: Use LaTeX to render the math.

Comment: Please strive not to [vote to reopen](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/1627597) dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't the question be 'for which $\theta$' ....

Then think along the unit circle.

Or use $\sin(x) + \cos(x) = \sqrt{2}\sin(x+\pi/4)$

Add $x$ and $y$ from any point, and compare it to the sum of $x'$ and $y'$ from the point at twice the angle.

Or use Wolfram Alpha to look for zeroes in: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin(x)+%2B+cos(x)+-+sin(2*x)+-+cos(2*x)